# Update CSS styles dynamically using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS and I'm not really sure how to create the effect I want using it.

I'd like to compare the values of two elements and conditionally update the CSS for the elements based on that comparison.

This seems very simple to do with jQuery or Vanilla JS, but I'm not sure how I can accomplish the same thing in an Angular app.

If I strip my code down, this is basically all I need to change.

**HTML:**

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Minimum Price</th>
      <th>New Price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <td ng-bind="sku.MinimumPrice"></td> <!-- value one -->
      <td>
        <input ng-model="sku.NewPrice" id="price-input"> <!-- value two -->
      </td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Pseudocode:**

```
if (sku.NewPrice > sku.MinimumPrice) {
  #price-input.style.color='red'
}
```

So, what is the 'Angular' way to implement this?

Comment: Where is your `newPriceInputElement` element in your HTML provided here?

Comment: @DavidR that would be the <input>, I will edit the question to make that more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Using ng-style tag](http://jsfiddle.net/0gc8arn3/):

```
<input ng-model="MinimumPrice"/>
<input ng-model="NewPrice"/>
<p ng-style="getStyle()">
 Text
</p>
```

---

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.getStyle = function(){
        var color = 'black';

        if ($scope.NewPrice > $scope.MinimumPrice) {
            color = 'red';
        }

        return {'color': color};
   }

}
```

Comment: Yeah, best way is using the controller and ngStyle.

Comment: This Worked for me as well. got more than 1 style,so i just create functions and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Angular has `ngStyle` for this purpose. This attribute let you change dinamycally your CSS using expressions and conditions.

Or you can use `ngClass` that let you change dinamycally any DOM class (and this is better, I think).

Ussage for `ngClass` is:

```
<ANY ng-class="{class: condition}">
```

So...

**Style.css**

```
.red {
    color: red;
}
```

**Template.html**

```
<input ng-model="sku.NewPrice" id="price-input" ng-class="{red: sku.NewPrice > sku.MinimumPrice}"
```

Hope this helps you :)